# Configure AWS Credentials so that robot framework AWS functions can be accessed in Jenkins

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, automation, robotframework

The jenkins pipeline is already configured with aws credentials.
I'm using robotframework-aws library to create an aws session.

It works fine when I run in local PC where I configure  ~/.aws/config file.

But when I deploy the code, in jenkins, it fails creating any session.

**Please suggest** how should I make the .robot file to create session using the credentials which is setup in Jenkins.

AWS Library from robot framework used are-

[pypi robot framework aws library](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-aws/)

[Create Session With Profile](https://www.roboscripts.org/libraries/awslibrary/)

Answer (score 0):

Using Jenkins [Credentials Binding](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/) plugin should answer your issue. You can see from the [plugin documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables) the different credential variable combinations you can use.

In Robot you'll need to add new variables for the credentials and then add the credential variables to the Robot launch command. Assuming you use variables user and pass, you can start robot with command like

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '<your-credentials-id>', usernameVariable: 'user', passwordVariable: 'pass')]) {
    robot -v USER:${user} -v PASS:${pass} <rest_of_the_command>
}
```

In Robot these can be then used like

```
Test Case
    Log    My username is ${USER}
```

Of course you should **not** log your user and password under any circumstance anywhere, I would recommend to use keyword `Set Log Level    None` until the credentials have been used. This prevents Robot from logging the variables on to the log file until restored with `Set Log Level    INFO`.